# EXCEL: Is there a function / way that works like LOOKUP, but takes an array as input and returns an array as results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

Is there a way in google spreadsheet to get array multiple values in return to an array of input values?

I am attaching an image that has an example of what is desired.

Basically, want something as:
=LOOKUP(input_array,range_with_ID_values,range_with_return_values)
which returns a 'result_array' that has an array of values matching with values from 'input_array'

Please help!
Kaustubh[image: want a f() that works like: '=f(input,range with IDs and colors)' retrns array the return box]

EDIT:
As a comment suggested, I am elaborating why I need this. I want to check if all dependent tasks are completed. if yes, then this 'dependent task' should open up to be taken up. Attaching an image to describe the scenario below

[click to see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUfLr.jpg)

In this image, until tasks 1,2,3 are not 'Completed', task 4 will always be 'Awaiting Dependency'. Once all tasks 1,2,3 are 'Completed', it will change to Pending

Also note that the tasks need not be serialized. There might be tasks in between, which are irrelavent to task we need to update status for. Eg. there may be tasks like 'buy grocery', 'kill cockroaches' etc which the 'water the plant' taks doesn't depend on

Comment: Yes, though that 'array' will be stored 'in-formula', e.g. to be further manipulated as desired, and not parsed into a single cell as a delimited list. Perhaps you should clarify which it is you are seeking.

Comment: is your input a comma delineated list in one cell?  Is your output a comma delineated list in one cell?  Or do you want the output to be use in another array formula?

Comment: yes, my list will be comma separated in one cell. It need not be enclosed in curly bracket or any bracket, though. 
And I do want to use the result further. I want to check if all the 'result values' are 'true'. If yes, then another cell should convert to 'true'. If any of these values from the array is 'false', it should return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)[excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula)

Use TEXTJOIN as an array formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & A2:A9 & ",","," & D3 & ",")),B2:B9,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correct then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function MultiReturn(rng As Range, inputs As String) As String
    Dim arry1, a, outstr As String, i As Long, arry2
    arry1 = Split(Mid(inputs, 2, Len(inputs) - 2), ",")
    outstr = "{"

    arry2 = rng
    For Each a In arry1
        For i = LBound(arry2, 1) To UBound(arry2, 1)
            If CStr(a) = CStr(arry2(i, 1)) Then outstr = outstr & arry2(i, 2) & ","
        Next i
    Next a

    MultiReturn = Mid(outstr, 1, Len(outstr) - 1) & "}"
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

As you see, the first argument is the table being search, the second argument is the set of inputs in your desired format *(curly brackets encapsulating a comma-separated list)*.